# Mysql:update trigger Error: Operand should contain 1 column(s)

Tags: mysql, triggers, phpmyadmin, eventtrigger

I created a trigger on each updation. So, whenever a student from class 'ABC' gets updated with the updated grade 'A' then the following nested case statements has to be executed. I am writing this code on Phpmyadmin. The current_status from table1 should be updated with the values from start_date to End_date

Whenever the xyz table updated with start_date and end_date
table1 should be executed like this:

### Start_date  current_status

### 1/1/2019      Good

### 2/1/2019      Moderate

### 3/1/2019      Good

### 4/1/2019      Good

5/1/2019      Moderate
When I run this it won't shows any error but when I update the table I get the following error

```
CREATE DEFINER=`xyz`@`localhost` TRIGGER `studentgrades`
AFTER UPDATE ON `table1` 
FOR EACH ROW 
update db.table1 h
SET

current_status =  
(
    CASE 
    when date(new.start_date) <= date(new.end_date) THEN
    CASE  
        WHEN new.student_class = 'ABC' and new.updated_grade='A' 
        THEN
        CASE
        WHEN statement 1 THEN  'Very Good'
        When statement 2 THEN  'Good'

        ELSE 'Moderate'
    END 

    ELSE 'Moderate'  
    END

   ELSE 'moderate'  
    END ,
     date(new.start_date) =date_add(date(new.start_date) , INTERVAL 1 DAY) 
   ) where  h.start_date = date(new.start_date);
```

MySQL said:

## 1241 - Operand should contain 1 column(s)

Comment: Isn't there something wrong with your parenthesis? It looks like you're doing `current_status = ( 'moderate', date(new.start_date) =date_add(date(new.start_date) , INTERVAL 1 DAY) )`. I think you can remove them alltogather: `current_status = CASE .... END , date ...`

Comment: once you get the syntax problem fixed, you're going to run into a MySQL limitation... it's not possible, within an update trigger, to execute an UPDATE on a table that is referenced in the statement that caused the trigger to be fired... 
assuming the table (unfortunately named) `table1` is in database (unfortunately named) `db1`.  Also, it's not possible to assign a value to the result of a function i.e. `DATE(NEW.start_date)`.  We could assign a value to NEW.start_date in the context of a `BEFORE INSERT` or `BEFORE UPDATE` trigger, but not in an UPDATE statement.

Comment: @Pepper If I remove parentheses, it shows the syntax error

Comment: @spencer7593 When I used    **when date(new.start_date) <= date(new.end_date)** , it started showing the error. Earlier without this statement it successfully updated the table

Comment: i wasn't referring to the condition in the WHEN clause... I was referring to the assignment in the `SET` clause, the second to last line, once the problem with the misplaced paren is corrected. If this trigger is on `db1.table1`, it's not possible to perform an `UPDATE` on `db1.table1` within the trigger.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by the comments, you will hit MySQL limitation on update triggers that you can't update the same table in the trigger body. You can change the After trigger to Before trigger

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE DEFINER=`xyz`@`localhost` TRIGGER `studentgrades`
BEFORE UPDATE ON `table1` 
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  SET NEW.current_status =  
    CASE 
      WHEN date(new.start_date) <= date(new.end_date) THEN
        CASE  
          WHEN new.student_class = 'ABC' and new.updated_grade='A' 
          THEN
            CASE
              WHEN statement = 1 THEN  'Very Good'
              When statement = 2 THEN  'Good'
              ELSE 'Moderate'
            END 
          ELSE 'Moderate'  
        END
      ELSE 'moderate'  
    END;
END
$$
```

Comment: This is cool. But, I need an increment statement also. Here I want to update current status from db1.table from start date till end date whenever there is an update in the table1 of a different database. Is it possible?

Comment: If the two tables are in different databases, the AFTER trigger works with no issue.

Comment: Thanks a lot I would try that

Comment: . What if I want to create a loop where the statements should run until date(new.start_date) = date(new.end_date). Because, this is causing me an error showing that 1241 - Operand should contain 1 column(s)

Comment: I believe that error was caused by  WHEN statement 1 THEN  'Very Good'
        When statement 2 THEN  'Good' in your original post, i.e. no equal (=) sign between statement and the number 1 and 2